# broken pipe error with python multiprocessing and socketserver

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, socketserver

Essentially Im using the socketserver python library to try and handle communications from a central server to multiple raspberry pi4 and esp32 peripherals. Currently i have the socketserver running serve_forever, then the request handler calls a method from a processmanager class which starts a process that should handle the actual communication with the client.

It works fine if i use `.join()` on the process such that the processmanager method doesnt exit, but thats not how i would like it to run. Without `.join()` i get a broken pipe error as soon as the client communication process tries to send a message back to the client.

This is the process manager class, it gets defined in the main file and `buildprocess` is called through the request handler of the socketserver class:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.allow_connection_pickling()

import queuemanager as qm
import hostmain as hmain


import camproc
import keyproc

import controlproc


# method that gets called into a process so that class and socket share memory
def callprocess(periclass, peritype, clientsocket, inqueue, genqueue):

    periclass.startup(clientsocket)


class ProcessManager(qm.QueueManager):

    def wipeproc(self, target):

# TODO make wipeproc integrate with the queue manager rather than directly to the class
        for macid in list(self.procdict.keys()):
            if target == macid:
                # calls proc kill for the class
                try:
                    self.procdict[macid]["class"].prockill()
                except Exception as e:
                    print("exception:", e, "in wipeproc")
                    
                # waits for process to exit naturally (class threads to close)
                self.procdict[macid]["process"].join()
                # remove dict entry for this macid
                self.procdict.pop(macid)
    



    # called externally to create the new process and append to procdict
    def buildprocess(self, peritype, macid, clientsocket):
        # TODO put some logic here to handle the differences of the controller process
        
        # generates queue object
        inqueue = mp.Queue()

        # creates periclass instance based on type
        if peritype == hmain.cam:
            periclass = camproc.CamMain(self, inqueue, self.genqueue)
        elif peritype == hmain.keypad:
            print("to be added to")
        elif peritype == hmain.motion:
            print("to be added to")
        elif peritype == hmain.controller:
            print("to be added to")
        
        # init and start call for the new process
        self.procdict[macid] = {"type": peritype, "inqueue": inqueue, "class": periclass, "process": None}
 
        self.procdict[macid]["process"] = mp.Process(target=callprocess, 
        args=(self.procdict[macid]["class"], self.procdict[macid]["type"], clientsocket, self.procdict[macid]["inqueue"], self.genqueue))

        self.procdict[macid]["process"].start()
        
        # updating the process dictionary before class obj gets appended
#        if macid in list(self.procdict.keys()):
#            self.wipeproc(macid)
        
            

        print(self.procdict)
        print("client added")
```

to my eye, all the pertinent objects should be stored in the procdict dictionary but as i mentioned it just gets a broken pipe error unless i join the process with `self.procdict[macid]["process"].join()` before the end of the `buildprocess` method

I would like it to exit the method but leave the communication process running as is, ive tried a few different things with restructuring what gets defined within the process and without, but to no avail. Thus far i havent been able to find any pertinent solutions online but of course i may have missed something too.

Thankyou for reading this far if you did! Ive been stuck on this for a couple days so any help would be appreciated, this is my first project with multiprocessing and sockets on any sort of scale.

#################

Edit to include pastebin with all the code:

https://pastebin.com/u/kadytoast/1/PPWfyCFT

Comment: There's quite some code missing, e. g. that of the _request handler_.

Comment: fs, i added the pastebin that has everything for reference, all hostmain really does is define a couple objects and start the server on a thread to serve forever, and then run a simple terminal interface for a couple things @Armali
idk if this helps, but reason wise i need a server script that can concurrently communicate with multiple peripherals over sockets, preferably in processes rather than threads since some of the peripherals will include video streams and i dont want that all to be in the same compute unit

Comment: I don't find the code at your pastebin link. Did you forget to make it public?

Comment: @Armali i think i had made it unlisted, i thought that would still show up with a direct link, im so sorry about that, it should be public and visible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Without `.join()` i get a broken pipe error as soon as the client communication process tries to send a message back to the client.

That's because at the time when the request handler `handle()` returns, the `socketserver` does `shutdown` the connection. That `socketserver` *simplifies the task of writing network servers* means it does certain things automatically which are usually done in the course of network request handling. Your code is not quite making the intended use of `socketserver`. Especially, for handling requests asynchronously, [Asynchronous Mixins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) are intended. With the [ForkingMixIn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ForkingMixIn) *the server will spawn a new process for each request*, in contrast to your current code which does this by itself with `mp.Process`. So, I think you have basically two options:

- code less of the request handling yourself and use the provided `socketserver` methods
- stay with your own handling and don't use `socketserver` at all, so it won't get in the way.

Comment: i see, thankyou for clearing that up! Also thankyou for sticking with all the formatting and information issues, i really appreciate it :)